# Cloud Functions problem, query resulting in an Array?

Tags: javascript, firebase-realtime-database, google-cloud-functions

I need to get inside of itens to go into some item, than into product to get the "ean" field and 
check if some product have the "ean" from the body request.

My database is organized like that:

```
"cart": {
  "itens": {
    "0": {info here},
    "1": {info here}
    "2": {
      "more info here",
      "product": {
         "avaliable": true"
         "quantity": 231,
         "ean": "0000001312"
      }
    continue listing until 47
```

But when I execute my cloud function:

```
exports.getItemByEan = functions.https.onRequest(async (request, response) => {
  const db = admin.database();
  const itens = db.ref();
  const eanRef = itens.child('carrinho').child('itens');
  const query = eanRef.orderByKey();

  try {
    const dataSnapshot = await eanRef.once('value');
    response.send(dataSnapshot.val());
  } catch (error) {
    console.log(error)
  }
  }) 

});
```

But i need to get inside of an iten, and then inside "product" field and than get the "ean", but the result of this is like an Array insted of an object, and without the keys appearing:

```
[
    {,
        "product": {
            "avaliable": true,
            "quantity": 9183
            "ean": "0000000000017",
    },
    {

   "product": {
            "avaliable": true,
            "quantity": 131
            "ean": "0000000044790",
        },
    },
    .....continues
```

I want to things, understand why the result of the query is an Array and not an Object with the Keys before the itens like in the Firebase Database, and then how is the better way to find the specific product by Ean.

I can't even do like

```
const db = admin.database();
const itens = db.ref();
const eanRef = itens.child('cart').child('itens').child('product'); // This doesnt works, just returns nothing, why ?????
// Isn't "product" field inside the item ?
```

Answer (score 1):

If your database keys are all numbers, then instead of an object, you will get an array with the same items, where the indexes of the array are the same as the keys of the nodes in the database.  Your code needs to be prepared for this.  So, if you want the client to receive an object instead of an array, you will have to convert it yourself.

Comment: I just want to access the "product" field to one task and make query that search into the database for the given item based on the "product.ean" field.